# How to get pm2 output without any formatting?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, text-formatting

I'm looking to run a command (via CLI on Ubuntu 16.04.3) and get my output without text formatting (colors, fancy ASCII characters, etc), and just regular text

Specifically, I need to do this for the output of [PM2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2)'s `pm2 monit` command.

Comment: I don't have pm2 but most Linux CLI programs have an option to turn off coloring like `--color=never` or `--no-color` you need to read pm2's help

Comment: Most Linux command detect if their output is a pipe/file or a direct TTY, and don't use color control characters in that first case.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Found my answer, I just needed to run `pm2 logs --raw`

Answer (score 4):

**pm2**'s **[Options](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/#options)** include `--no-color`. So you just need to use that:

```
   ...
   --no-color                           skip colors
   --no-vizion                          skip vizion features (versioning control)
   --no-autorestart                     do not automatically restart apps
```

For more details & references, visit [Quick Start](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/) and [One Page Documentation](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-doc-single-page/).

Comment: Well first off, running `pm2 --no-color` just [returns nothing](https://gyazo.com/66ae41a510004bbe68c6979dfc336803), and 2nd, I want to be able to **just** have the log output come up.

Comment: it should be used as an addition to your normal command. Did you run `pm2 logs --no-color` or `pm2 monit --no-color`? And most Linux apps automatically disable coloring when piping to another process, so did you try that?